# How to find whether a PDF file has overlapping text or not, using c#

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, overlapping

I have several PDF files, using a Windows application (C#), I need to find out whether the PDF files has overlapping text or not. How can I do it, is there any free third party DLLs to achieve this?
All I have got now is third party DLLs which can get the text/images from a PDF. [image]

My PDFs are full of texts and images. Here, one line of text is printed on top of another line or few texts are printed on top of some images. These kind of overlapping needs to found.

As you can see in the image, those overlapping might have occurred because of bounding boxes overlap and as well as glyphs contours overlap. So these two occurrences in the PDF needs to be found. My PDF doesn't contain any annotations. So overlapping occurs only in the content of pdf. We don't use poor-man's-bold technique for fatter glyph and if that occurs then it shoul be consider as overlapping.

There is not going to be any transparent images in the PDF, only image we might have is the logo or the digital signature at the bottom of the page, any text overlaps this should be considered as overlapping.

PDFs are not created from image(scan). From some text editor it has been created.

Comment: i think it is possible if the pdf is generated from text editors and not from image(scan)

Comment: @rajeemcariazo PDFs are not created from image(scan).  From some text editor it has been created.

Comment: iTextSharp may have a feature that determines the coordinates of strings in PDF

Comment: @rajeemcariazo, ok, using string coordinates how to find the overlap. Can you please explain it bit more?

Comment: By *overlapping text* do you mean that the actual glyph contours overlap or that the glyph bounding boxes overlap? If e.g. a string of space characters happens to be drawn diagonally over the page across many lines, would that be overlapping (because bounding boxes overlap) or not (because space characters are empty, so there is nothing to overlap)? Furthermore, sometimes PDF creators use a poor-man's-bold by drawing the glyphs twice with a minute offset, making it look like a fatter glyph. Would that be overlapping text (as two distinct glyphs overlap) or not (as it is meant as one char)?

Comment: @mkl, My PDFs are full of texts and images. Here, one line of text is printed on top of another line or few texts are printed on top of some images. These kind of overlapping needs to found. I don't  have much knowledge on glyph bounding boxes or glyph contours.

Comment: That does not answer the question. Are you talking about the respective bounding boxes overlapping, or are you talking of the actual glyph contours overlapping. But one thing in you comment is new, you now also are talking about text overlapping images, not merely text overlapping text. On that issue: If text only is on an image where the image is white (or transparent), does that have to be recognized as *overlapping text*?

Comment: @mkl, I have added a snapshot of what I'm talking or trying to find from the PDF file.

Comment: Can you share sample PDFs? The screenshot does not answer the clarification requests above.

Comment: @mkl, PDF files are highly confidential, what clarifications you want, I will try to answer them. Thanks.

Comment: **1.** Are you talking about the respective bounding boxes overlapping, or are you talking of the actual glyph contours overlapping? **2.** If text only is on an image where the image is white (or transparent), does that have to be recognized as overlapping text? **3.** Does the overlapping occur in the page content or may also annotations be involved? **4.** Sometimes PDF creators use a poor-man's-bold by drawing the glyphs twice with a minute offset, making it look like a fatter glyph. Would that be overlapping text (as two distinct glyphs overlap) or not (as it is meant as one char)?

Comment: As you can see in the image, those overlapping might have occurred because of bounding boxes overlap and as well as glyphs contours overlap. So these two occurrences in the PDF needs to be found.  My PDF doesn't contain any annotations. So overlapping occurs only in the content of pdf.  We don't use poor-man's-bold technique for fatter glyph and if that occurs then it shoul be consider as overlapping.

Comment: There is not going to be any transparent images in the PDF, only image we might have is the logo or the digital signature at the bottom of the page, any text overlaps this should be considered as overlapping.

Comment: Ok. (So there is no need to check for images overlapping each other, I suppose.) I'll try and write up an answer.

Comment: I'm in the process of writing something up. I'm in a similar position as Alexander (user3099949), though: By your not sharing sample PDFs you make us guess a lot and we cannot say whether there is something special about your PDFs we have to keep in mind..

Answer (score 3):

The OP clarified in comments:

- > those overlapping might have occurred because of bounding boxes overlap and as well as glyphs contours overlap. So these two occurrences in the PDF needs to be found.

  Whenever the glyph contours themselves overlap, their bounding boxes also overlap.

  Thus, **it suffices to check for overlapping bounding boxes.**
- > only image we might have is the logo or the digital signature at the bottom of the page, any text overlaps this should be considered as overlapping.

  Thus, **for text overlapping images we do not need to check whether a blank area in the image is overlapped.**
- > My PDF files doesnt have any annotations.

  Thus, **we only need to check the page contents** (including contents of form xobjects referenced from the page content, allowing recursion).
- Furthermore the OP only mentioned text and images. Thus, **we can ignore vector graphics.**

### An approach using iText 7

As I'm more into Java, I first created a prove-of-concept in Java and ported it to .Net later.

Both for Java and .Net the line of action is the same:

- We create a event listener for the iText 7 parsing framework which (while processing a page) collects the bounding boxes of text and image elements and eventually can be asked to check whether there are any occurrences of text overlapping text or image.
- We parse the content of the page in question using an instance of that event listener class and query it for overlaps. If more pages are to be checked, this can be done over and over again with a new event listener instance for each page.

#### iText 7 for .Net

The event listener might look like this:

```
class OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy : IEventListener
{
    static List<Vector> UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS = new List<Vector> { new Vector(0, 0, 1), new Vector(1, 0, 1), new Vector(1, 1, 1), new Vector(0, 1, 1) };

    ICollection<Rectangle> imageRectangles = new HashSet<Rectangle>();
    ICollection<Rectangle> textRectangles = new HashSet<Rectangle>();

    public void EventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type)
    {
        if (data is ImageRenderInfo) {
            ImageRenderInfo imageData = (ImageRenderInfo)data;
            Matrix ctm = imageData.GetImageCtm();
            List<Rectangle> cornerRectangles = new List<Rectangle>(UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS.Count);
            foreach (Vector unitCorner in UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS)
            {
                Vector corner = unitCorner.Cross(ctm);
                cornerRectangles.Add(new Rectangle(corner.Get(Vector.I1), corner.Get(Vector.I2), 0, 0));
            }
            Rectangle boundingBox = Rectangle.GetCommonRectangle(cornerRectangles.ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine("Adding image bounding rectangle {0}.", boundingBox);
            imageRectangles.Add(boundingBox);
        } else if (data is TextRenderInfo) {
            TextRenderInfo textData = (TextRenderInfo)data;
            Rectangle ascentRectangle = textData.GetAscentLine().GetBoundingRectangle();
            Rectangle descentRectangle = textData.GetDescentLine().GetBoundingRectangle();
            Rectangle boundingBox = Rectangle.GetCommonRectangle(ascentRectangle, descentRectangle);
            if (boundingBox.GetHeight() == 0 || boundingBox.GetWidth() == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Ignoring empty text bounding rectangle {0} for \"{1}\".", boundingBox, textData.GetText());
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Adding text bounding rectangle {0} for \"{1}\" with 0.5 margins.", boundingBox, textData.GetText());
                textRectangles.Add(boundingBox.ApplyMargins<Rectangle>(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, false));
            }
        } else if (data is PathRenderInfo) {
            // TODO
        } else if (data != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ignored {0} event, class {1}.", type, data.GetType().Name);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ignored {0} event with null data.", type);
        }
    }

    public ICollection<EventType> GetSupportedEvents()
    {
        // Support all events
        return null;
    }

    public bool foundOverlappingText()
    {
        bool result = false;
        List<Rectangle> textRectangleList = new List<Rectangle>(textRectangles);

        while (textRectangleList.Count > 0)
        {
            Rectangle testRectangle = textRectangleList[textRectangleList.Count - 1];
            textRectangleList.RemoveAt(textRectangleList.Count - 1);

            foreach (Rectangle rectangle in textRectangleList)
            {
                if (intersect(testRectangle, rectangle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found text intersecting text with bounding boxes {0} at {1},{2} and {3} at {4},{5}.",
                            testRectangle, testRectangle.GetX(), testRectangle.GetY(), rectangle, rectangle.GetX(), rectangle.GetY());
                    result = true;// if only the fact counts, do instead: return true
                }
            }
            foreach (Rectangle rectangle in imageRectangles)
            {
                if (intersect(testRectangle, rectangle))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found text intersecting image with bounding boxes {0} at {1},{2} and {3} at {4},{5}.",
                            testRectangle, testRectangle.GetX(), testRectangle.GetY(), rectangle, rectangle.GetX(), rectangle.GetY());
                    result = true;// if only the fact counts, do instead: return true
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    bool intersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b)
    {
        return intersect(a.GetLeft(), a.GetRight(), b.GetLeft(), b.GetRight()) &&
                intersect(a.GetBottom(), a.GetTop(), b.GetBottom(), b.GetTop());
    }

    bool intersect(float start1, float end1, float start2, float end2)
    {
        if (start1 < start2)
            return start2 <= end1;
        else
            return start1 <= end2;
    }
}
```

This event listener can be used like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
PdfDocumentContentParser contentParser = new PdfDocumentContentParser(document);
OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy strategy = contentParser.ProcessContent(page, new OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy());
bool foundOverlaps = strategy.foundOverlappingText();
```

#### iText 7 for Java

The event listener might look like this:

```
public class OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy implements IEventListener {
    static List<Vector> UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS = Arrays.asList(new Vector(0,0,1), new Vector(1,0,1), new Vector(1,1,1), new Vector(0,1,1));

    Set<Rectangle> imageRectangles = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Rectangle> textRectangles = new HashSet<>();

    @Override
    public void eventOccurred(IEventData data, EventType type) {
        if (data instanceof ImageRenderInfo) {
            ImageRenderInfo imageData = (ImageRenderInfo) data;
            Matrix ctm = imageData.getImageCtm();
            List<Rectangle> cornerRectangles = new ArrayList<>(UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS.size());
            for (Vector unitCorner : UNIT_SQUARE_CORNERS) {
                Vector corner = unitCorner.cross(ctm);
                cornerRectangles.add(new Rectangle(corner.get(Vector.I1), corner.get(Vector.I2), 0, 0));
            }
            Rectangle boundingBox = Rectangle.getCommonRectangle(cornerRectangles.toArray(new Rectangle[cornerRectangles.size()]));
            logger.info(String.format("Adding image bounding rectangle %s.", boundingBox));
            imageRectangles.add(boundingBox);
        } else if (data instanceof TextRenderInfo) {
            TextRenderInfo textData = (TextRenderInfo) data;
            Rectangle ascentRectangle = textData.getAscentLine().getBoundingRectangle();
            Rectangle descentRectangle = textData.getDescentLine().getBoundingRectangle();
            Rectangle boundingBox = Rectangle.getCommonRectangle(ascentRectangle, descentRectangle);
            if (boundingBox.getHeight() == 0 || boundingBox.getWidth() == 0)
                logger.info(String.format("Ignoring empty text bounding rectangle %s for '%s'.", boundingBox, textData.getText()));
            else {
                logger.info(String.format("Adding text bounding rectangle %s for '%s' with 0.5 margins.", boundingBox, textData.getText()));
                textRectangles.add(boundingBox.applyMargins(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, false));
            }
        } else if (data instanceof PathRenderInfo) {
            // TODO: vector graphics
        } else if (data != null) {
            logger.fine(String.format("Ignored %s event, class %s.", type, data.getClass().getSimpleName()));
        } else {
            logger.fine(String.format("Ignored %s event with null data.", type));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<EventType> getSupportedEvents() {
        // Support all events
        return null;
    }

    public boolean foundOverlappingText() {
        boolean result = false;
        List<Rectangle> textRectangleList = new ArrayList<>(textRectangles);

        while (!textRectangleList.isEmpty())
        {
            Rectangle testRectangle = textRectangleList.remove(textRectangleList.size() - 1);

            for (Rectangle rectangle : textRectangleList) {
                if (intersect(testRectangle, rectangle)) {
                    logger.info(String.format("Found text intersecting text with bounding boxes %s at %s,%s and %s at %s,%s.",
                            testRectangle, testRectangle.getX(), testRectangle.getY(), rectangle, rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY()));
                    result = true;// if only the fact counts, do instead: return true
                }
            }
            for (Rectangle rectangle : imageRectangles) {
                if (intersect(testRectangle, rectangle)) {
                    logger.info(String.format("Found text intersecting image with bounding boxes %s at %s,%s and %s at %s,%s.", 
                            testRectangle, testRectangle.getX(), testRectangle.getY(), rectangle, rectangle.getX(), rectangle.getY()));
                    result = true;// if only the fact counts, do instead: return true
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    boolean intersect(Rectangle a, Rectangle b) {
        return intersect(a.getLeft(), a.getRight(), b.getLeft(), b.getRight()) &&
                intersect(a.getBottom(), a.getTop(), b.getBottom(), b.getTop());
    }

    boolean intersect(float start1, float end1, float start2, float end2) {
        if (start1 < start2)
            return start2 <= end1;
        else
            return start1 <= end2;
    }

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy.class.getName());
}
```

This event listener can be used like this:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdf);
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(reader);
PdfDocumentContentParser contentParser = new PdfDocumentContentParser(document);
OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy strategy = contentParser.processContent(pageNumber, new OverlappingTextSearchingStrategy());
boolean foundOverlaps = strategy.foundOverlappingText();
```

#### Remarks

As you can see I don't store the text bounding boxes as they are but instead

```
boundingBox.applyMargins(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, false),
```

i.e. slightly smaller boxes. This is done to prevent false positives which otherwise might occur for tightly set text or text with kerning applied. You may have to fine tune the margin values here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm getting the following errors, I'm using itext7 in .NET. 1. Set<Rectangle> , Set<EventType>, Set<EventType> - I'm getting "the type or namespace name Set<> could not be found". 2. Arrays doesnt contain definition for 'asList'. 3. this.imageRectangles  cannot be used in foreach because it doesn't contain public definition for 'GetEnumerator'. I guess all these errors are because of .NET

Comment: I will port that to iText 7 for .Net and c#.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm eagerly waiting for it.

Comment: @KarthikJaganathan I added a port to C# / iText 7 for .Net.

Comment: Your code works well, could you please suggest how could we get the overlapping text?

Comment: @user423574 *"could you please suggest how could we get the overlapping text?"* - you could store the rectangle together with the text in them in `eventOccurred` by using a `Map` instead of a `Set`. Then you have the text at hand in `foundOverlappingText` when determining overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

It may be as easy as the example above or you have to implement your own reader for this.

If you have not the full control over your PDF files, you have no chance to solve your problem. The defined boxes can be transformed later on. So you have to parse the whole file, too keep track of the box position and form. Additionally some boxes may be on top of other boxes, but render without any collision on the pixel level.

Than you will run into the next problem. Each PDF implementation has different errors. So your system may render the text perfectly but not the printer of your customer.

Welcome to hell ;)

Each support guy will tell you that they obey the standard. The others must have implemented their PDF library faulty. Because your customers data will be confident, you cannot proof them wrong. You may find some errors with your test data, but never ever the same errors of your customer documents.

Run and hide as long as you have not become the PDF expert of your company.

---

Here is a dirty "general" method: render your text without the text in bitmap. render the page with your text in another bitmap, compare the area with your text. But this will need a monochrome background. But the load will be really high. But this document looks like a form. Create a form and fill out the form boxes. So you will have no problems and you will even get correct results, fills the form with another program

Comment: While there is much truth in your answer, it does not really answer the question and, therefore, is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: Yes. But in real life will no one pay for it. A general solution will be much too complex. You need full control over the PDF process. But than it will be easier to place the boxes manually than detecting collisons.If cannot store the position meta data outside the document, you can simply place them inside comments.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have a code sample that uses not free library, but I think other libraries should have similar functionality, so you may use it as the idea:
**Before use the following code sample please ensure that you use the latest version of the Apitron PDF Kit.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout.Content;
using Apitron.PDF.Kit.FixedLayout.PageProperties;

using FixedLayout.Resources;
using FixedLayout.ContentElements;

        /// <summary>
    /// Gets all text boundaries.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="elements">The elements.</param>
    /// <param name="boundaries">The boundaries.</param>
    public void GetAllTextBoundaries(IContentElementsEnumerator elements, IList<Boundary> boundaries, Boundary offset)
    {
        // We dont count drawings and images here - only text;
        if(elements == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        foreach (IContentElement element in elements)
        {
            TextContentElement text = element as TextContentElement;
            if (text != null)
            {
                foreach (TextSegment segment in text.Segments)
                {
                    Boundary currentBoundary = segment.Boundary;

                    if (offset != null)
                    {
                        currentBoundary = new Boundary(currentBoundary.Left + offset.Left, currentBoundary.Bottom + offset.Bottom, currentBoundary.Right + offset.Left, currentBoundary.Top + offset.Bottom);
                    }
                    boundaries.Add(currentBoundary);
                }
            }
            else if (element is FormContentElement)
            {                    
                Boundary currentBoundary = (element as FormContentElement).Boundary;
                if (offset != null)
                {
                    currentBoundary = new Boundary(currentBoundary.Left + offset.Left, currentBoundary.Bottom + offset.Bottom, currentBoundary.Right + offset.Left, currentBoundary.Top + offset.Bottom);
                }
                this.GetAllTextBoundaries((element as FormContentElement).FormXObject.Elements, boundaries, currentBoundary);
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if text is overlapped.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CheckIfTextIsOverlapped(string fileName)
    {
        const double overlapMax = 5;

        using (System.IO.Stream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            using (FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument(stream))
            {
                foreach (Page page in document.Pages)
                {
                    IList<Boundary> boundaries = new List<Boundary>();
                    foreach (Annotation annotation in page.Annotations)
                    {
                        // Actually we need only Normal state, but will check all - to be sure.
                        if(annotation.Appearance.Normal != null)
                        {
                            this.GetAllTextBoundaries(annotation.Appearance.Normal.Elements, boundaries, annotation.Boundary);
                        }
                    }
                    IContentElementsEnumerator elements = page.Elements;
                    this.GetAllTextBoundaries(elements, boundaries, null);

                    for (int i = 0; i < boundaries.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = i + 1; j < boundaries.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Boundary b1 = boundaries[i];
                            Boundary b2 = boundaries[j];

                            double x1 = Math.Max(b1.Left, b2.Left);
                            double y1 = Math.Max(b1.Bottom, b2.Bottom);
                            double x2 = Math.Min(b1.Right, b2.Right);
                            double y2 = Math.Min(b1.Top, b2.Top);

                            // So we have intersection
                            if (x1 < x2 && y1 < y2)
                            {
                                if (x1 - x2 >= overlapMax || y1 - y2 >= overlapMax)
                                {
                                    return true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are the `Boundary` instances the *boundary boxes* of the text segments or are they the paths defined by the glyph's outlines?

Comment: The boundary is the bbox of the text segment - if glyph's outlines are overlapped, their bboxes will be overlapped too

Comment: right, if the glyph outlines overlap, so should their bounding boxes do, too. But not necessarily the other way around, and one can interpret the op's question and comments to imply that he doesn't care about bounding boxes, only about the glyph outlines.

Comment: Agree, you are right. But as a rude solution it should be ok. Perhaps the tool has an ability to extract outlines of glyphs, to get the correct solution.

Comment: This solution doesn't help me in finding the overlapped texts in my PDF files. Thank you.

Comment: It is because the file has annotations - and they overlaps the page content. This code does not count annotations. I've corrected the code sample

Comment: My PDF files doesnt have any annotations.

Comment: Could you send me the file ? I will find a solution.

Comment: Perhaps I understand why it did not work for you ! The page contains XObjects, so just add a code that parses XObject's text(recursively)  and all will work fine.

Comment: @Alexander, I will try to share the PDF files, I don't have much knowledge on PDF objects like XObjects etc, so could you please make necessary changes in your code, so that I can test it. Thanks.

Comment: @Alexander, if you dont mind, could you please help me on this.

Comment: I have updated the code sample, please check it out for your PDF file.

Comment: @Alexander, in the function CheckIfTextIsOverlapped, I'm not able to find a function or property named "AllContents", I'm getting that annotation.Appearance doesn't contain a definition for 'AllContents'. What I'm I missing?

Comment: I have used Apitron.PDFKit - 1.0.76, version from NUGET.

Comment: Just use Appearance.Normal

Comment: According to the @Karthik's comments to his question, his *"PDF doesn't contain any annotations."* Has this turned out to be wrong?

Comment: It is common solution, some files may have annotations.

Comment: @Alexander, couldn't able to use Appearance.Normal in a foreach loop, because it doesn't contain any public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: I have updated the code sample. could you please send me your pdf file ?